# Resultset in session

Tags: java, session

What are the disadvantages of placing resultset in session? if not which is the best possible way.I tried to place it in a `List<Map<String,String>>`,does it not affect the performance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `ResultSet` represents an open connection to the database; generally you want to get your data out and return the connection to the pool as quickly as possible. Storing a `ResultSet` in the session leaves open the possibility that the connection won't be closed for a long time, which could exhaust the pool, or unnecessarily tie up your database resources.

Answer (score 3):

Persistence classes from `java.sql` should not come within 100 feet of the web tier.  They should never escape from the persistence layer.  You need to load every `ResultSet` into a data structure or object in method scope in which it was created and close it.  It's a database cursor, a scarce resource.

Your best option isn't `List<Map<String, String>>`; after all, every value in the database isn't a String.  Better to use `List<Map<String, Object>>` where the Map represents a row.  Another possibility is `Map<String, List<Object>>`, where each `List<Object>` represents a column.  Use the one that's most convenient for your use case.  Best of all, use `List<T>`, where `T` is the type of an object that ties all those columns in a real way.