# Performance issue with resultset

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Resultset in session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674150/resultset-in-session)

i have a query which builds a resultset,which is has some three lakh (300k) records.And the resultset is placed in the session.i tried to improve by iterating resultset and place it in List>.But  even after using this,we have performance issues.Is there any other way for this?

Comment: You add a question previously (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674150/resultset-in-session) about storing a resultset in the session. The answers you got told you not to do it. You haven't accepted any answer, and you don't follow the advice you got. Why should we help you?

Comment: Moreover, do you really think we can solve your performance issues without having any idea of the code you're running?

Comment: See the post i had previously was in different application.

Comment: So you think that just because the application is different, suddenly storing a resultset in a session becomes a good idea? Read and try to understand the answers you got. It's ALWAYS a bad idea.

Comment: i'm not placing the resultset in session.but replacing that with List

Comment: So, why do you say in your question: "And the resultset is placed in the session" [sic]?

Comment: 300K records in session !! Who's design is that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a very bad idea to load such huge number of rows into memory and especially putting them into session.  You need to implement pagination - modify the query to fetch a subset of rows and then when you need the next set execute a query again.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there's another way--don't put it in session.

Here's the thing: we don't know *why* you're putting it in the session, because you don't provide any details.

For pagination? Use a limit/offset mechanism and only request the current page's results.

For reporting? Generate the report at the end of whatever data narrowing functionality you're using and only store criteria in the session.

Or...?